# Execute Javascript embedded inside the HTML souce page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to automate a scenario where my HTML contains Javascript as below:

```
<SCRIPT language="javaScript" src="DLR/temp/dlrclientCode.js">
```

Where `dlrclientCode.js` has a `function addRecord()`.

Can anyone explain how I can run the function `addRecord` embedded inside the Javascript `dlrclientCode.js` from Python.

Comment: How does the user invoke the method?

Comment: Can you show us your code trial? You need to find the `WebElement` which calls `dlrclientCode.js` in it's `onClick()` event and invoke `click()` on that element.

Comment: Share your code and which JS event do you want to handle?

Comment: I am finding the webelement using below code

Comment: please find the below the below code.

url = "xxxx.com"
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

webelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//SCRIPT [@src='DLR/temp/dlrclientCode.js']")[0].click
#after fetching dlrcclientCode.js web element I am trying to execute a java function addrecord() which is embedded inside the JS dlrcclientCode.js

please help me how can achieve the same.